Fuzzing with AFL++ (how to start)
I have a simple program that will crash (using strcpy) but I am having problems trying to crash it with AFL++. I am simulating a closed source binary fuzzing.
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char dest[4];
    strcpy(dest, argv[1]);

    printf("%s\n", dest);

    return 0;
}

My AFL++ command line is as follows
./afl-fuzz -i ./testcases/ -o ./findings_dir -Q -- ../src/strcpy_arm64_linux z

My input test case consists of only one file which contains "zzzz".
My questions are

What should I do to get it to fuzz correctly? I waited for 10 minutes or so, should I wait longer?
Do I still need to specify an input folder with input files given that I have provided a command line parameter in my command (the single "z")?
How do the input files come into effect? When and how do the contents of the input files get used during the testing?
Where can I see the various permutations that the fuzzer is trying?


Afl writes mutated data to a file and your binary should read it from the file. Easiest way - pass @@ instead of z in the command line and rewrite the code to read the data from a file, whose name is passed in argv[1].

Yeah in the end thats what I did to test the fuzzing.
